# Need output in a good format using shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have a file, `PoolReport.txt`. Here is some sample data:

```
Thu, Aug 27, 2015 7:56:29 AM
PoolName,Total GB,Used GB ,Available GB ,Percent Full
Oracle-RAID10,6432.539,6179.295,253.244,96.063
VM_File,45210.379,40726.389,4483.991,90.082
Oracle-RAID5,15025.039,12289.707,2735.332,81.795
```

I need it in the following format.

```
Thu, Aug 27, 2015 7:56:29 AM
PoolName       Total GB   Used GB    Available GB   Percent Full
Oracle-RAID10  6432.539   6179.295   253.244        96.063
VM_File        45210.379  40726.389  4483.991       90.082
Oracle-RAID5   15025.039  12289.707  2735.332       81.795
```

---

I managed to produce a better format (as below), but it does not satisfy the needs.

```
awk -F "," '{print $1"\t" $2"\t" $3"\t" $4"\t" $5"\t" }' PoolReport.txt
```

```
Thu      Aug 27  2015 7:56:29 AM
PoolName        Total GB         Used GB        Available GB    Percent Full
Oracle-RAID10   6432.539        6179.295        253.244 96.063
VM_File 45210.379       40726.389       4483.991        90.082
Oracle-RAID5    15025.039       12289.707       2735.332        81.795
```

Comment: Wait. You're asking us to _ask your question for you?_

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I understand your question properly, but I believe you want to align the columns. If that is the case then the command `column` is handy:

```
column -s, -t file
```

Output:

```
Thu             Aug 27     2015 7:56:29 AM
PoolName       Total GB    Used GB          Available GB   Percent Full
Oracle-RAID10  6432.539   6179.295          253.244        96.063
VM_File        45210.379  40726.389         4483.991       90.082
Oracle-RAID5   15025.039  12289.707         2735.332       81.795
```

Or, if you want to keep first line as is, then

```
{ head -n 1; column -s, -t; } <file
```

Output:

```
Thu, Aug 27, 2015 7:56:29 AM
PoolName       Total GB    Used GB   Available GB   Percent Full
Oracle-RAID10  6432.539   6179.295   253.244        96.063
VM_File        45210.379  40726.389  4483.991       90.082
Oracle-RAID5   15025.039  12289.707  2735.332       81.795
```

See `man column` for possible options you may want to add to tune the output.

Comment: (1) Of course you *don’t* need the terminal semicolon and the separating spaces if you use parentheses: `(head -n 1; something else)`.  As I’m sure you two (jimmij and Peter.O) know, `(command(s))` is functionally equivalent to `{ command(s); }` if the command(s) don’t alter the shell’s state (`cd`, set variables, etc.).  I believe that the `(…)` version spawns an extra process, which is resource-wasteful in a trivial way, but I seem to recall hearing otherwise (“the shell needs to fork to run the command(s) either way”).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d)  … (2) The original version of the question had blank lines probably because the OP didn’t know how else to get line breaks; it’s unclear whether they ever were present in his data.

Comment: @Scott Sure, one can use subshell `()` as well.

Comment: re: `column`. Whether or not the OP's input was single or double spaced, the output from `column` would be the same, as `column` ignores empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

Change all occurrences of `,` to `{tab}`, except on the first line:

```
sed '2,$s/ *, */\t/g' PoolReport.txt
```

OR format the fields with tab separators, except on the first line:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1;NR>1{OFS="\t"; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' PoolReport.txt
```

Output for either instance:

```
Thu, Aug 27, 2015 7:56:29 AM
PoolName        Total GB        Used GB Available GB    Percent Full
Oracle-RAID10   6432.539        6179.295        253.244 96.063
VM_File 45210.379       40726.389       4483.991        90.082
 Oracle-RAID5    15025.039       12289.707       2735.332        81.795
```